# Android: displaying images from url in imageview

Tags: android, image, url, imageview

*Screenshot*
[Gridview Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E497f.png)

I have been trying to display images from url in this GirdView. Some images appear fine, but some images are not appearing correctly. I am also saving the images in cache for making it show images faster next time. This is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.gridview;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageList
    .add("http://wallpapersus.com/wallpapers/2012/10/Megan-Fox-22-854x960.jpg");
    imageList.add("http://www.wallpapersdesign.net
    /wallpapers/2013/12/Transformers-Megan-Fox-854x960.jpg");
    imageList
            .add("http://wallpapersus.com/wallpapers/2012/10/Megan-Fox1-854x960.jpg");
    imageList
    .add("http://wallpapersus.com/wallpapers/2012/10/Megan-Fox-24-854x960.jpg");

    imageList
    .add("http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2013/06/Wallpapers-Megan-Fox-11-854x960.jpg");
    imageList
            .add("http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2013/06/Megan-Fox-133-854x960.jpg");


    imageList
            .add("http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2013/06/Megan-Fox-89-854x960.jpg");

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageList));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(1));
}

class OnImageClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    public int position;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> v, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FullScreenViewActivity.class);
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putStringArrayList("url", imageList);
        basket.putString("position", String.valueOf(arg2));
        i.putExtras(basket);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        Log.e("Activity ImageClass", "Left from this class");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        refresh();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    private void refresh() {

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageList));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(1));
    }
}
```

**This is the adapter**

```
package com.example.gridview;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mContext;
ArrayList<String> imageList;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
ProgressDialog progress;
int versionCode = 10;

public ImageAdapter(Activity c, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
    mContext = c;
    this.imageList = imageList;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext, 200);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            Log.e("Inside", "if");
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setId(position);
        } else {
            Log.e("Inside", "else");
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 90));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }

    } else {

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    //imageLoader.clearCache();
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageList.get(position), imageView);

    return imageView;
}
}
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
package com.example.gridview;

public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
public int REQUIRED_SIZE;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
Activity context;

public ImageLoader(Activity context, int size) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context, size);
    this.context = context;
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    REQUIRED_SIZE = size;
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_menu_camera;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void setWallpaper(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(context);
        // below line of code will set any image which is in the
        // drawable
        // folder
        // myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.icon);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height,
                true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(context);
        // wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void DisplayImageCircle(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }

}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(6000000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(6000000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

I also tried running imageLoader in `doInBackground()` but it was of no use.
Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

set your url also in ImageView

```
imageView.setTag(yourURL);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageList.get(position), imageView);
```

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but I don't understand how it is gonna help. Will you please explain your answer ?

Comment: @PrashantYadav when you set method DisplayImage you pass only two parameters First Url and Second Imageview
In Imageloader library download using thread, for more images thats in thread run background if that url is Null then find by imagesview tag.
And Second Thing before set Image in Imageview that Compare URL and tag.

Comment: Sir, as you can see in http://imgur.com/wJBfHZq, some images are appearing fine, but some imageviews are displaying only a portion of image, so will it help?

Comment: @PrashantYadav yes. Use ImageLoder library or Aquery.